# How to Get a string out of a URL in PHP

Tags: php, string, url, curl

I am grabbing a bunch of data via an API using curl, and this is the code:

```
function query($connectorGuid, $input, $userGuid, $apiKey, $additionalInput) {

          $url = "https://api.import.io/store/connector/" . $connectorGuid . "/_query?_user=" . urlencode($userGuid) . "&_apikey=" . urlencode($apiKey);

          $data = array("input" => $input);
          if ($additionalInput) {
            $data["additionalInput"] = $additionalInput;
          }

          $ch = curl_init($url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);

          return json_decode($result, true);
        }

        // Query for tile Bundesliga Stats
        $result = query("73df0478-4e6e-4f78-9ab5-f9866ac7a531", array(
          "webpage/url" => "http://some_url.com/results_name/1234",
        ), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
        var_dump($result);
}
```

I posted the entire code in case it's needed, but what I really need is the last part:

```
$result = query("73df0478-4e6e-4f78-9ab5-f9866ac7a531", array(
      "webpage/url" => "http:/some_url.com/result_name/1234",
    ), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
```

Is there a way there a way to set that URL to a variable somehow and then set the "result_name" part of the URL to another variable?

Answer (score 0):

You posted this:

```
$result = query("73df0478-4e6e-4f78-9ab5-f9866ac7a531", array(
      "webpage/url" => "http://some_url.com/result_name/1234",
    ), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
```

But then ask this:

> Is there a way there a way to set that URL to a variable somehow and
>   then set the "result_name" part of the URL to another variable?

Is there a reason why you cannot do something like this:

```
$URL/$result_name/1234
```

So your code would be something like:

```
$URL = "http://some_url.com";
$result_name = "result_name";
$result = query("73df0478-4e6e-4f78-9ab5-f9866ac7a531", array(
      "webpage/url" => "$URL/$result_name/1234",
    ), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
```

Or maybe this to make it easier to understand:

```
$URL = "http://some_url.com";
$result_name = "result_name";
$result = query("73df0478-4e6e-4f78-9ab5-f9866ac7a531", array(
      "webpage/url" => $URL . "/" . $result_name . "/1234",
    ), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
```

Or hey, look at that `1234`.  The URLs have a lot of parts. So why not do it this way instead:

```
// Create a URL array for all of the parts.
$URL_array = array();
$URL_array[] = "some_url.com";
$URL_array[] = "result_name";
$URL_array[] = "1234";

// Then set the result and use `implode` to create a coherent string from that URL array.
$result = query("73df0478-4e6e-4f78-9ab5-f9866ac7a531", array(
      "webpage/url" => "http://" . implode("/", $URL_array),
    ), $userGuid, $apiKey, false);
```

Comment: I see what your saying. However, I have about 100 of those to do, each with a different "result_name" so I was looking for someway to extract it out of each url. Does that make sense?